# String case sensitive in LiteDB query

Tags: litedb

In various environment, the user name is case insensitive. We query `admin` equal to `ADMIN`. I have searched `LiteDB` called `CompareTo` to compare two objects that I can't find a point to make string compared as case insensitive.

The code in `QueryEquals.cs`

```
internal override IEnumerable<IndexNode> ExecuteIndex(IndexService indexer, CollectionIndex index)
{
    var node = indexer.Find(index, _value, false, Query.Ascending);

    if (node == null) yield break;

    yield return node;

    if (index.Unique == false)
    {
        // navigate using next[0] do next node - if equals, returns
        while (!node.Next[0].IsEmpty && ((node = indexer.GetNode(node.Next[0])).Key.CompareTo(_value) == 0))
        {
            if (node.IsHeadTail(index)) yield break;

            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

The propositional we can case insensitive

```
using (var db = new LiteRepository("lite.db"))
{
    db.Insert(new User { Name = "John" });
    var user = db.Query<User>()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "JOHN")
        .FirstOrDefault(); // proposal return John
    var fail = db.Query<User>()
        .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "JOHN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .FirstOrDefault(); // throw exception
}
```

Another consideration, it is a possible to execute lambda expression in LiteDB without conversion by visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LiteDB v4, you can use expressions to make sure that the index of username is stored as lowercase, then you can perform a "lowercase-compare"

```
// Create index
entity.EnsureIndex(e => e.Username, "LOWER($.Username)");
...
// Find user
collection.Find(e => e.Username == username.ToLower);
```

If you dont want to use expressions, I guess that you could make sure the username is lowercase before saving in LiteDB or you can use an index less query (slower) by using collection.Where (not quite sure on that method though).

Comment: Yeah, it is a answer, but not a best solution. At least, this is a best way in current stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this without having to create an additional index:

```cs
// Works.
Query.StartsWith("LOWER($.Username)", input.ToLower());
```

To be honest I'm not exactly sure what happens under the hood, I don't know if "Username" needs to be indexed for it to work, and my attempts to create an index based on the same expression did not work:

```cs
// Doesn't work.
Collection.EnsureIndex("SearchByUsername", "LOWER($.Username)", false);
```